# Add two list of integer

Tags: python

Python beginner here! I want do a nested for loop to add two integer list. But somehow I can't get last index of list. Could anyone help please?

```
num_cases = [500, 800, 900, 1000]
num_predic = [10, 20, 30]
predict( num_predic,num_cases)
def predict(cases, predicted_growths):
    new_cases = []
    for elem in range(len(predicted_growths) + 1 ):
        for elems in range(len(cases)):
            grow = cases[elem] + predicted_growths[elems]
            new_cases.append(grow)
            if len(new_cases) == len(cases):
                new_cases.insert(len(new_cases),predicted_growths[-1] + cases[-1])
                #Since I don't know how to reach the last 
                #index of list. Then I found out insert() method. Still doesn't work it will 
                #print same value three times.
                print(new_cases)
                new_cases = []
                break
```

my output:

```
[510,810,910]
[520,820,920]
[530,830,930]
```

output suppose look like this:

```
[510,810,910,1010]
[520,820,920,1020]
[530,830,930,1030]
```

Thank you so much for help!

Comment: Get out of the habit of using `for index in range(len(list)):`. Use `for item in list:`

Comment: You're stopping before the last case because of `if len(new_cases) == len(cases):`

Answer (score 1):

You're making this too hard.

```
num_cases = [500, 800, 900, 1000]
num_predic = [10, 20, 30]
def predict(cases, predicted_growths):
    for predic in predicted_growths:
        new_cases = [case+predic for case in cases]
        print(new_cases)

predict(num_cases, num_predic)
```

Now, there are better ways to do this, but this show you the keys.  Don't worry about indices.  Just enumerate the values.

At least one person has tried to edit this to swap the loops.  Don't do that.  What I have here is correct.  Output:

```
[510, 810, 910, 1010]
[520, 820, 920, 1020]
[530, 830, 930, 1030]
```

Comment: I think you have the loops backwards. The main loop should be over `cases`.

Comment: Nope.  Look at his output.  There is one line per predictions value.  That has to be the outer loop.  I looked at it twice before I posted...

Comment: But `num_predic` is the `cases` parameter.

Comment: The variable names are confusing.

Comment: Bah, you're right.  I'll swap them.

Comment: Or he's just calling it wrong.

Comment: Thank you so much for you help!

Answer (score 0):

Just to make it really simple, Tim Roberts answer being good, this is the same but maybe easier to understand for a beginner.

```
num_cases = [500, 800, 900, 1000]
num_predic = [10, 20, 30]

for np in num_predic:
    row=[]
    for nc in num_cases:
        row.append(np+nc)
    print(row)
```

Output is:

```
[510, 810, 910, 1010]
[520, 820, 920, 1020]
[530, 830, 930, 1030]
```

Comment: Thank you so much!